# Android navigation drawer indicator not pure white

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create Navigation drawer indicator pure white. But it has little blue shade.

[image: screenshot]

How can I do it? I used Android asset studio to create indicator ([link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)).

Comment: go to same link and select custom and custom color white

Comment: i have added the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current icon is little transparent

select custom and custom color white

[image]

Comment: Did you replace new images?